# Importing Archilogic scene into A-frame

Tags: archilogic, 3d.io

I came across this scene (scene ID # 71c8eef9-b44e-447f-a0d2-fd299318da56) on one of the examples on stackoverflow. When I use that scene id as in the code below in a-frame.

`io3d.scene.getAframeElements('71c8eef9-b44e-447f-a0d2-fd299318da56').then(elems => { document.querySelector('a-scene').appendChild(elems[0]) })`

I can see the scene with perfect position and scale. However, when I use the scene I developed (scene id: 8f769bc6-4a0e-4bb4-bfaa-8580ac93f88f) using the same code in a-frame, the house displays as a very small object and position is also not correct. There is no difference in the code for both the scenes but the scale and position differs for both of them.

I tried to play around with position and scale attributes but it did not work. Could you kindly help understand what could be the difference? Thanks, Niraj

Answer (score 2):

Your model is positioned very far from the origin of the worl, that means it is (110.86, 88.96) meters away from the center.

[image: Position]

when you use `io3d.scene.getAframeElements` it will take the position and scale from the original scene.

you have the following options:

1) change your camera position to match the offset of the model

2) move the model to the center by changing positions of the elements

3) use the [appcreator](https://appcreator.3d.io/) to create your aframe scene with the correct setup (here is an example of your [scene](https://app.3d.io/iotxqW)

4) adjust the scene in spaces.archilogic.com

Hope that helps!